# Convert extended value to Time

Tags: delphi, floating-point, extended-precision

I want to convert a extended value to time.
before the DecimalSeparator is hours
after the decimalseparator are minutes digital

```
8,62944444444444  --> 8:37
1,41666666666667  --> 1:25
```

I've made this funtion but I get for 1,41666666666667  --> 1:24 
It must be 25 minutes

```
function MyConvertion(AValue: Extended): TDateTime;
var
    Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word;
begin
  Hour:= Trunc(AValue);
  Min:= Trunc(Frac(AValue)*60);
  result:= EncodeTime(Hour, Min, 0, 0);
end;
```

When I use exact 1,41666666666667 I'm get 1:25
But the value I must convert comes out from a soap enterface as double (oPostCalculationDay.DirectAssignedWorkTime).

The value I get in debug mode = 1,41666666666667

```
MyConvertion(1,41666666666667) --> 1:25
MyConvertion(oPostCalculationDay.DirectAssignedWorkTime) --> 1:24
MyConvertion(RoundTo(oPostCalculationDay.DirectAssignedWorkTime, -15)) --> 1:25
MyConvertion(RoundTo(oPostCalculationDay.DirectAssignedWorkTime, -16)) --> 1:24
MyConvertion(strtofloat(floattostr(oPostCalculationDay.DirectAssignedWorkTime)))--> 1:25
```

I'm thinking is something like [Floating points](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html)

But what is the best methode I must use? Roundto -14 because 1,41666666666667 is 14 numbers after the separator of something else?

Comment: That's where I would use `TTimeSpan.FromMinutes()`. I don't see the place for `TDateTime` here.

Comment: @TLama thanks it works with System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan.FromHours

Comment: @Ravaut Please don't answer in the question. I reverted.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that the values are encoded like this:

```
Hours + Minutes/60
```

where `Hours` and `Minutes` are integers and `Minutes` is between 0 and 59 inclusive.

You need to round the minutes rather than truncate them

```
Min := Round(Frac(AValue)*60);
```

If the fractional part contains seconds or even milli-seconds then you need a different calculation.

```
Secs := Round(Frac(AValue)*3600);
```

or

```
MSecs := Round(Frac(AValue)*3600000);
```

I don't see much point in using extended here. That type only exists distinct from double on x86 and in any case is slower than double due to poor alignment, and gives you nothing here that you cannot get from double.

Comment: This give me 1:25 for 1,41666666666667 but 8:38 for 8,62944444444444. The solution is this from TLama

Comment: I would have rounded to milliseconds. It is likely that 1:24:59 should be displayed as 1:24.

Comment: @LURD the question suggests to me that hours and minutes have been encoded using hours + minutes/60

Comment: 8,62944444444444 is 8:37:46.

Comment: @LURD When I debug I get 8,62944444444444 but it is more than that.

Comment: Ravaut, even so, 8.62944444444445 is also 8:37:46.

Comment: @LURD I was looking at .4166 recurring. I guess that Ravaut ought to know how the value is encoded.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the suggestion to change extended to double and also add the seconds